# Azure Functions Blob Output binding puts quotation marks in path when accessing activityTrigger

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I want to create a Blob on my storage with a dynamic path depending on the first parameter of a Durable Function Activity. While accessing the parameter works, the path then contains quotation marks. In Python.

The resulting file on my storage is then named data_"someid".npz. How can I do this without having  quotation marks in the name?

My json looks like this, notice the out path containing {userid}

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "userid",
      "type": "activityTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "outfile",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "path": "azfuntest/data_{userid}.npz",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

from init.py:

```
async def main(userid: str, outfile: func.Out[func.InputStream]) -> str:
   ...
```

calling it from my orchestrator_function:

```
context.call_activity("MyActivity", "someid")
```

Function Tools: V3

pip azure-function-blob: 12.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function definition you are passing userid as str, so it will be considered as str, adding to this you are passing “userid” as name in bindings so doubt quotes are updating. Instead, you can follow below format.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "info",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "webHookType": "genericJson"
    },
    {
      "name": "blobContents",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "strings/{BlobName}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    },
    {
      "name": "res",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here name is different and passing the parameter in the path is different. BlobName should be passed from the function.

Also, for more information, check the [documentation of bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns) to know how to pass values and handling binding errors